# Rails 3 - data from form are printed twice

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have simple form:

```
<%= form_tag('/paymentShops/newww') do -%>
<table class="adm_prehled"><tr>
    <% i = 0%>
    <% for dopr in @settings %>
      <% i += 1 %>
        <td class="posl_import">
            <%= check_box_tag 'settings['+dopr.id.to_s+']', dopr.id%>
            <%= dopr.value %>
        </td>
        <% if i == 4%>
            </tr><tr>
            <% i = 0%>
        <%end%>
    <% end %>
</tr> </table>  
<div><%= submit_tag('Sent') %></div>
<% end -%>
```

and in controller

```
  def newww
    params[:settings].each do |page|
      puts page
    end
  end
```

and in terminal I am getting always the statement from puts twice... e.g.: I will select the inputs with numbers 3, 5, 9, co I will get in terminal:

> 33
>
> 55
>
> 99

Could anyone help, me, please, what is wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
        <%= check_box_tag 'settings[]', dopr.id%>
```